# Vector Layer Symbology Export?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis, symbology

When programmatically creating / saving a QgsVectorLayer - implementation of the ExportSymbology functionality does not seem to exhibit the implied effects.

Does such a command not indicate that the layer style is restored when reopening or loading the shapefile at a later time (could be off on interpretation of this function)?

```
        writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(str(someFileName), "CP1250", some.fields, \
             QGis.WKBPoint, some.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile", \
             symbologyExport=QgsVectorFileWriter.FeatureSymbology)
```

Comment: Same problem, Does anybody discover a solution?

Comment: Shapefiles will not contain Symbols (only geometry, point.line or polygon), you can export (or store symbols in spatiallite/postgres etc from QGIS)